# Creating log file with extension 'log'

Tags: c#, logging, streamwriter

I want to create a log file with extension 'log' but a simple text file is created (txt) but when I create a data file with extension 'dat' it works.

```
var ext = ".log";
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(dir + @"\" + title + ext))
{
   sw.Write(rows);
   sw.Flush();
}
```

or

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(dir + @"\" + title + ext))
{}
```

I would like to show extension ".log" in file name.
Could someone help me, please?

Comment: You are trying to create your logger? Or log something from your program??

Comment: Never heard/seen that the c# classes modifies the extension names. It should be something else.

Comment: You assume the file has no extension, but it is most likely working fine but windows file explorer is hidding the known extensions

Comment: By default Windows hides _known_ file extensions. Windows probably doesn't know what a `.dat` is.

Comment: It could be, the first thing i turn off. **Useless feature**.. Some ignorant people will open this 'image'   `nicepicture.jpg.exe`   <-- but thats another discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do assume that your file is created correctly. You just do not see .log extension in explorer because of its default settings:

[image]